# import_request_variables() Not Working in IIS 7

Tags: php, windows, iis

I have just switched to IIS to encapsulate all my server needs and installed PHP 5.4.4 (latest) successfully; however, `import_request_variables()` is being labeled undefined.  My script worked on my old Apache setup but not here.  Any suggestions on IIS-specific settings that I may need to tweak?  Thanks.

Go to `http://75.66.61.141/prj/canommonon` to see of which I speak.  It may be down because that's my laptop and I move it to my office.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.import-request-variables.php

`import_request_variables()` Support has been removed since 5.4.0

Comment: Is there a way to include the functionality (with a function that accomplishes the same obviously) globally to all scripts?

Answer (score 0):

why do you wanna use import_request_variables()?
You can write a function with the same result, I think.